# Is there a simpler way to write (a == b && b == c && c == d) in Java?

Tags: java

If I want to check if all 4 integers are the same, is there shorter version than the one in the title?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 4):

```
Set.of(a, b, c, d).size() == 1  // EDIT: WRONG!!
```

I mean, *I really would **not** do that*.

**Edit:** Stuart Marks points out that `Set.of` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if there are duplicate elements. Alternative:

```
Set.copyOf(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d)).size() == 1
```

or if you're desperate for a short expression:

```
copyOf(asList(a, b, c, d)).size() == 1
```

(Assuming excessive static imports.)

Comment: That is really cute.

Comment: @PM77-1 Too cute.

Comment: I think it is much harder to understand, where as the question is about a simpler way. But I like that your idea is not trivial, the code is compact, and voted your answer up.

Comment: I think that will throw an exception if any of the elements are equal. How about `Set.copyOf(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d)).size() == 1` ?

Comment: @StuartMarks Oh blast. I always forget the oddities. In my defence, the exception isn't documented directly in the method docs.